# TableView Navigation using JSON (database data)

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I used the following tutorial to create a TableView Navigation: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_TableView_Navigation_using_Xcode_Storyboards but with that example I can show static information.

Now I need to display images and texts from my database and I need some help to do that.

At the moment, that's my **CarTableViewController.m**

```
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewCell.h"
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"

@implementation CarTableViewController

@synthesize carMakes = _carMakes;
@synthesize carModels = _carModels;
@synthesize carImages = _carImages;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc]
                     initWithObjects:@"Chevy",
                     @"BMW",
                     @"Toyota",
                     @"Volvo",
                     @"Smart", nil];

    self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"Volt",
                      @"Mini",
                      @"Venza",
                      @"S60",
                      @"Fortwo", nil];

    self.carImages = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"chevy_volt.jpg",
                      @"mini_clubman.jpg",
                      @"toyota_venza.jpg",
                      @"volvo_s60.jpg",
                      @"smart_fortwo.jpg", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.carModels count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [self.carMakes
                           objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [self.carModels
                            objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:
                         [self.carImages objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];

    cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                                    indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects: [self.carMakes
                                                                 objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               [self.carModels objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               [self.carImages objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               nil];
    }
}

@end
```

I need to put the information from my database (author, date and picture) to carMakes, carModels and carImages to display it. I can get the values from my PHP file with JSON, but I need some help with the NSArray with JSON result because I never used it.

How can I do that?

That's my JSON result:

```
[{"id":"15","user":"1","image":"http:\/\/farmaventas.es\/images\/farmaventaslogo.png","date":"2014-09-13"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have your data organized wrong.  Have a single array per section, and have the elements of the arrays be dictionaries.  Then you can just about parse your JSON and plop it right in there (though it's usually better to have a routine that copies each row's data to a new dictionary to clean things up a bit).

Comment: Can you show me an example, please? Thanks @Hot Licks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* chevyVolt = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
chevyVolt[@"Make"] = @"Chevy";
chevyVolt[@"Model"] = @"Volt";
chevyVolt[@"Image"] = @"chevy_volt.jpg";
dataSource[0] = chevyVolt;
NSMutableDictionary* clubman = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
-- etc --
```

Inside cellForRow--

```
NSMutableDictionary* cellData = dataSource[[indexPath row]];
cell.makeLabel.text = cellData[@"Make"];
cell.modelLabel.text = cellData[@"Model"];
-- etc --
```

When you receive your JSON data, you have to decide what row it pertains to.  If you somehow know that id 15 is for a Chevy Volt, you then presumably copy info out of the corresponding JSON element into the dictionary for the Chevy Volt.  (Or, if you wait to receive the JSON to add the Chevy Volt row (seems more likely), you construct the dictionary for the Volt as above and add it to the end of the dataSource array, with the added info from the  JSON.)

Comment: Hi Hot Licks. I found myself in something like that and I need help with that because I load the info with a custom PHP file and then I output the info like JulienKP in JSON format. How can I go on? I have to copy your code? Thanks @Hot Licks.

Comment: Thanks @Hot Links, but I also want to know what I have to do after I show my JSON result because I'm a little bit lost. Can you show me an example of how to do that for my JSON?

Comment: @JulienKP - I have no idea how you plan to match your JSON data with the car data.  Technically it's not hard, but you need to know how you want things related.